# keep delimititers on preg_match_all php

Tags: php, string, split

I would like to split strings on different delimiters but in the created array I would like to have the delimiter as well. I was trying the following pattern on `preg_match_all` but the delimiter is not getting parsed.

```
$text = "100€ Rabatt";
preg_match_all('/([^+,&euro;]+)([+,GRATIS])*/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

this one outputs

```
  0 => '100', 
  1 => 'Rabatt'
```

expected would be

```
  0=>'100€',
  1=>'Rabatt'
```

Comment: Why do you think that € is an html entity (`&euro;`) rather than a UTF-8 character?

Comment: when I var_dump the content of $text I get 50&euro; Rabatt

Comment: The string that you've posted here isn't `50&euro;` so your example doesn't match your reality

Comment: sorry my mistake the var_dump is 100&euro; Rabatt

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a match if you run `htmlentities` on your text first before the match.

```
$text = htmlentities($text);
```